# How to display subnormal numbers in c?

Tags: c

I try to check subnormal numbers. Below is my code. It works, but I do not see a difference between Min positive normal number and subnormal number.
Why ?

```
/* 
isnormal  example 

ISO C99
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isnormal/
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Classes.html
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_math.html


compile with: 
gcc -std=c99 -lm s.c

run :
./a.out

*/
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* isnormal, fpclassify */



int TestNumber(double x)
{
  int f; // flag

  f= isnormal(x);
  if (f) 
    printf ("number %f is normal \r",x);
    else printf ("number %.1000f is not normal \n",x);

  return f;

}

//----------------------------

int main()
{

  double d ;
  double MinNormal; 
 int f;
  

  d = 1.0 ; // normal
  f = TestNumber(d);
  do 
  {
   d /=2.0;
   MinNormal=d;
   f = TestNumber(d);
   }
  while (f);

 
  printf ("number %.1000f is minimal normal \n",MinNormal);

  printf ("number %.1000e is not normal \n",d);
  printf ("number %.1000e is minimal normal \n",MinNormal);
  
  
  
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my output :

```
gcc -std=c99 -lm s.c
a@acer:~/cnie/numerical/subnormal/s1$ time ./a.out
number 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111253692925360069154511635866620203210960799023116591527666370844360221740695909792714157950625551028203366986551790550257621708077673005442800619268885941056538899676600116523980507372129181803596078252347125186710418762540332530832907947436024558998429581982425031795438505915243739989044387687497472579022580252545769992829123540932255676896790249605799054288302599621667605717619507439784980479564444580149632075553173315669683173879325651468588102366281589074283217543606141431882102242340570380695573853140084492662205501208072371080928358307527007714254235837645095158066138944836485368656166704349449158753391942346304638698898642932982747054568454770306823378435119933915764534049231 is not normal 
number 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111253692925360069154511635866620203210960799023116591527666370844360221740695909792714157950625551028203366986551790550257621708077673005442800619268885941056538899676600116523980507372129181803596078252347125186710418762540332530832907947436024558998429581982425031795438505915243739989044387687497472579022580252545769992829123540932255676896790249605799054288302599621667605717619507439784980479564444580149632075553173315669683173879325651468588102366281589074283217543606141431882102242340570380695573853140084492662205501208072371080928358307527007714254235837645095158066138944836485368656166704349449158753391942346304638698898642932982747054568454770306823378435119933915764534049231 is minimal normal 
number 1.1125369292536006915451163586662020321096079902311659152766637084436022174069590979271415795062555102820336698655179055025762170807767300544280061926888594105653889967660011652398050737212918180359607825234712518671041876254033253083290794743602455899842958198242503179543850591524373998904438768749747257902258025254576999282912354093225567689679024960579905428830259962166760571761950743978498047956444458014963207555317331566968317387932565146858810236628158907428321754360614143188210224234057038069557385314008449266220550120807237108092835830752700771425423583764509515806613894483648536865616670434944915875339194234630463869889864293298274705456845477030682337843511993391576453404923086054623126983642578125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e-308 is not normal 
number 1.1125369292536006915451163586662020321096079902311659152766637084436022174069590979271415795062555102820336698655179055025762170807767300544280061926888594105653889967660011652398050737212918180359607825234712518671041876254033253083290794743602455899842958198242503179543850591524373998904438768749747257902258025254576999282912354093225567689679024960579905428830259962166760571761950743978498047956444458014963207555317331566968317387932565146858810236628158907428321754360614143188210224234057038069557385314008449266220550120807237108092835830752700771425423583764509515806613894483648536865616670434944915875339194234630463869889864293298274705456845477030682337843511993391576453404923086054623126983642578125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e-308 is minimal normal
```

================edit===============

good program after applaying all the changes from the answers and comments

```c
  while (f)
  {
    MinNormal=d;
    d /=2.0;
    f = TestNumber(d);
   }
```

and print only 16 digits:

```
printf ( "number %.16e is normal \n",x);
```

Comment: Why exactly are you printing out 1000 digits?

Comment: You want to change that `\r` to `\n` in your first `printf()` call, too, it's never flushing that output when I run it as written, and it's not printing in our output, either.

Comment: I thought that I will find a small difference. The truth is that it was really the same number ( see answer below)

Comment: @Adam A double only has around 15 significant figures. All the extra digits you are printing are implementation-dependent, and meaningless since they provide no additional information. If two doubles are different, the difference will be in the first few digits.

Comment: @Thomas: The extra digits are not meaningless and are not implementation-dependent on implementations that conform to IEEE 754-2008, which requires that conversions to decimal are either correctly rounded for all digits or are correctly rounded up to some implementation-dependent bound and zero after that, and the standard recommends that the bound be infinite. While many people use floating-point in a way such that digits after the first few convey little information to them, when exploring the floating-point system itself, as this question does, all of the digits may be meaningful.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your point is well-taken, but in the case of comparing two doubles (which is what this question is concerned about) they are meaningless because if two doubles `a` and `b` are close but not equal, then their printed representation (`%.*f`) must differ in the first 15 or so digits by definition. So the comparison here does not require printing out 1000 digits.

Comment: @Thomas: If a person wants to see the digits, satisfying their desire requires displaying the digits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fair enough. I'm just saying that OP's program, within the question's scope, doesn't require that many digits to be meaningful. He is of course free to do whatever he wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way your loop is written, it always ends with `d` and `MinNormal` set to the same value. You should move the assignment of `MinNormal` before the change to `d` so that it remembers the value of `d` from the previous iteration.